# Hover "Drop Right" Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, tailwind-css

I am trying to implement a side-menu that would expand a "table" of items when you hover over one of its items. I'm using TailwindCSS and React.

The problem I'm facing is that **the menu does not expand when I hover over the button**.

I've made the sub-menu a child of the button so that I could use the group-hover functionality, but it does not work. I already added `display: ['hover', 'focus']` to the variants config, so, that can't be the problem.

```js
// SideMenuItem.js

import React from "react";

function SideMenuItem() {
  return (
    <button className="group static m-2 w-16 h-16 bg-red-400"> A
    
      <div className="hidden group-hover:block relative top-0 left-24 w-48 z-10 flex flex-row flex-wrap bg-gray-300">
        <button className="m-2 h-16 w-16 bg-gray-200">Item 1</button>
        <button className="m-2 h-16 w-16 bg-gray-200">Item 2</button>
        <button className="m-2 h-16 w-16 bg-gray-200">Item 3</button>
      </div>
    </button>
  );
}

export default SideMenuItem;
```

Desired Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this code sample from an article.
https://codesandbox.io/s/59574892-so-n-number-of-dropdowns-9hkt3

Try to understand what the man did and write it on your own.
Best of luck!

Comment: That example uses bootstrap tho. I was looking for a solution using tailwind.

Comment: My bad, try this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IF6k0uZuypA&ab_channel=Fireship 

 The dude copy's facebooks dropdown, that will show you how it's done and you learn.
 Let me know if it works